# How do I detect a zoom event in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to detect a zoom event in Highcharts? My use case is that I have some state external to the chart, and when the user zooms in on part of it I want to detect what the new time range on the x-axis is and update the corresponding external state.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Have you tried going through the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)?

You may want to look @ 
[xAxis.events.setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.setExtremes)
And/Or
[chart.events.selection](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.selection)

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want. It was really non-obvious to me that "setExtremes" is what happens when the user zooms, but oh well.

Comment: glad to help, I highly recommend to explore their api, they have some really good documentation with jsFiddle examples

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the redraw event as well. When you zoom, the chart is redrawn to reflect the changes. [chart.events.redraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw)

```
events: {
    redraw: function(){
        console.log(this.xAxis);
        console.log(this.yAxis);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems unnecessary, redraw is called much more often then needed in this case. Also, does not answer the question as to how to check if there was a zoom event

Comment: in highmaps, this seems to be the only solution as there is no zoom event - thanks for answer +1 (can easily debounce redraw func)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using redraw global event:

```js
{
  redraw: function(event) {
    if (
      (event ? .target ? .axes[0] && event ? .target ? .axes[0].max !== event ? .target ? .axes[0].oldMax) || 
      (event ? .target ? .axes[1] && event ? .target ? .axes[1].max !== event ? .target ? .axes[1].oldMax)) {
        // Here you can be sure the this is closer to a zoom event... almost, because it also detect drag on the map :(
      }
  }
}
```

I just want to leave this here because I decide to use something else but my future self might need it :D