# Highcharts - add minor ticks on zoom?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column chart with Y zooming enabled.  I would like to show the minor tick lines on zooming in, and remove them on zooming out.  I know how to [detect the zoom event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12324034/988264), and determine if it is zooming in or resetting the zoom, but I can't seem to get the minor tick lines to show.

I would like to do something like this:

```
yAxis: {
    events: {
        setExtremes: function (event) {
            if (event.min === undefined) {
                this.minorTickInterval = undefined;
            } else {
                this.minorTickInterval = 1;
            }
        }
    }
},
```

But that's not working.  I also tried calling `this.chart.redraw()` after setting the tick interval, but that doesn't work either.

How can I show and remove the minor tick lines dynamically?

Comment: How about using the `Axis.update()` method? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.update Also, check the docs for how `minorTickInterval` works - `1` will not show anything: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minorTickInterval

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Put it down as an answer...

Comment: I don't see anything there that implies that `1` will not work, and in fact it does work in my case.

Comment: Ok, correction, 1 may or may not work, depending on your axis values :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `Axis.update()` method in this case, rather than directly updating the object property.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.update